# NextAuth - OAuthAccountNotLinked - Imported data from another website - Autolinking

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, next.js, onelogin, next-auth

I have OneLogin setup in my application and is working fine. Am using MongoDB database for storing the sessions, accounts and users.
And now, I imported user data from my old WordPress website(which doesn't uses OneLogin, but the native WordPress login).

So basically I imported the user data from WordPress and populated the users collection using the email_id, name, etc. When I login with the OneLogin into my application, it throws the error saying OAuthAccountNotLinked. When researched I can see that you are not recommending the auto-linking of user accounts for safety reasons. But in my case, it's a OneLogin provider that my client's organization that has now started using. And new OneLogin user registrations are manually approved by the admin. So security wise it won't be a problem. We are only using OneLogin as auth provider!

How can I setup auto-linking in this scenario? Because I have 10,000s of Users in my MongoDB collection(imported from old WordPress website). And each User is being requested to manually register at OneLogin using the same email id they were using before in the old WordPress website and is manually approved within the OneLogin.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to find a straight forward solution, I come up with a workaround. It's not a perfect solution, but does the job. Maybe someone else will post a better solution here.

So what I did is, I have all the old user data imported to the `users` collection in my MongoDB database. And NextAuth uses this `users`, `accounts` and `session` collections to store the User and related data. Btw am storing the session data in database.

In my case, we have sent unique OneLogin registration URLs(created from the OneLogin Admin Dashboard) to our existing users for them to create a new account in OneLogin. Then when the User registers an account at OneLogin, the admin approves/rejects the User. If they are approved, they will be eligible to login to our app using their OneLogin credentials.

What I noticed is that, when a User tries to login, NextAuth checks the `email` field in `users` collection to find a matching record. Since we imported the Users from WordPress database, we only have records in `users` collection and nothing on the `accounts` collection. In `accounts` collection, NextAuth is storing the access_token, user_id (mapping to `users` collection), provider details, etc.

So during login, the NextAuth does the internal checks and finds the existing `email` in the `users` collection, but it fails to identify the user as there's no info about the provider(OneLogin) details.

Record from `accounts` collection:
[image]

So what I did is, updated all records in `users` collection by appending a `_TEMP` to the `email` field's values. For example, if there's a record with the value `abc@abc.com`, it will become `abc@abc.com_TEMP`

Then what I did is, I wrote an API route(`/api/check_old_account`) in my NextJS application, where it does the following:

- gets the currently logged in User's email id (from NextAuth session)
- searches the `users` collection for the same email id with a "_TEMP" at the end
- if there exists a `_TEMP` version of the currently logged in User, then return a response saying an old account exists

Then in the HOME page, I wrote the code to call the above mentioned api (`/api/check_old_account`) if the User is logged in. This call is made only once in the HOME page, when everything is loaded. Here the login using OneLogin works without errors because we renamed the existing email id in `users` collection by appending `_TEMP`. So when User logins, the `users` collection inserts a new record with their email and related data to the `accounts` collection also. Basically there would be two records in `users` collection for that User now. One is their original email id record that got inserted now when the logged in (eg: `abc@abc.com`) and their old imported account (eg: `abc@abc.com_TEMP`). The reason why I wrote the code to call the API in the HOME page only is because, after User logs in, they will be redirected to the HOME page. So thought it won't be necessary to write the code globally or somewhere else.

So, if the above API response says that there's an old account that exists, I display a warning popup to the User saying that there's an old account existing in the database and asks whether they want to link that old account. If the User presses YES button, I make an API call to `/api/link_old_account`. In this API route, the code is written to perform this:

- if there's a `_TEMP` version `email` of the currently logged in user in `users` collection, find the respective record `_id` that has mappings in the `accounts` collection.
- then change the value of the `userId` field of that respective record(currently logged in user id) in `accounts` collection, with the user id of the record with the `_TEMP` version email.
- then delete the record with the `_id` of the currently logged in user
- then update the `email` field by removing the `_TEMP` from it
- then deletes the records that matches the currently logged in user in the `userId` field of `sessions` collection. So that the currently logged in sessions of this User would be invalidated.
- then redirects the user back to the HOME page using `res.redirect(307, '/')`

The solution seems to be working fine so far.

Comment: This also works fine (after adding the logic) with `next-auth`'s `prisma` `connector`, which relies on a barebones approach to e.g. the `user` `model`/`table`. Adding (optional!) `relation`s to your own app's `user`, `account` etc works fine, you have to 'hydrate'/populate them when the user is confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Quote right from the original [site](https://next-auth.js.org/faq)

> Automatic account linking on sign in is not secure between arbitrary providers - with the exception of allowing users to sign in via an email addresses as a fallback (as they must verify their email address as part of the flow).
>
> When an email address is associated with an OAuth account it does not necessarily mean that it has been verified as belonging to account holder — how email address verification is handled is not part of the OAuth specification and varies between providers (e.g. some do not verify first, some do verify first, others return metadata indicating the verification status).
>
> With automatic account linking on sign in, this can be exploited by bad actors to hijack accounts by creating an OAuth account associated with the email address of another user.
>
> For this reason it is not secure to automatically link accounts between arbitrary providers on sign in, which is why this feature is generally not provided by authentication service and is not provided by NextAuth.js.
>
> Automatic account linking is seen on some sites, sometimes insecurely. It can be technically possible to do automatic account linking securely if you trust all the providers involved to ensure they have securely verified the email address associated with the account, but requires placing trust (and transferring the risk) to those providers to handle the process securely.
>
> Examples of scenarios where this is secure include with an OAuth provider you control (e.g. that only authorizes users internal to your organization) or with a provider you explicitly trust to have verified the users email address.
>
> Automatic account linking is not a planned feature of NextAuth.js, however there is scope to improve the user experience of account linking and of handling this flow, in a secure way. Typically this involves providing a fallback option to sign in via email, which is already possible (and recommended), but the current implementation of this flow could be improved on.
>
> Providing support for secure account linking and unlinking of additional providers - which can only be done if a user is already signed in already - was originally a feature in v1.x but has not been present since v2.0, is planned to return in a future release.

You probably need to write your own implementation to handle such a situation. And call that implementation on each provider call back. Like a check, the email already exists in DB, through an extra level of verification like OTP etc. Finally, when everything passes, let the user in and store some extra info in the DB for future reference.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I already saw this in the documentation. I was expecting for a workaround. Because we are in a controlled environment, where the OneLogin users are manually approved by the admins. So the concern of security risks can be ruled out.

Comment: it requires manual coding to comply with specific logic, I'm on to it to solve my scenario. Will share on success.

Comment: I update the description with some hints, an example code would be available when I can have some time to work on that.

Comment: Thanks. But am looking forward for the actual implementation. Because I couldn't find any useful info from their documentation to override this default checking.

Comment: Should have an option to allow `autoLink` or provide a work around, I am using `@auth/prisma-adapter` and get stuck with the issue, I think it is common that many systems have existing users.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the oAuthAccountNotLinked error, and in my case, it was caused because an account record already existed but not an user one, i had deleted the user instance in my db but not the account one (using mongoDb provider).